# Cocos 2d, gradual changing of a sprite's color

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am setting a color to my sprite using the setColor method, However at some point, i need to set it to a different color. By calling setColor again, I can change the color to the new color. But, I want to color change to be gradual, like an animation. How do I achieve this in Cocos 2d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Tint action

```
[yourSprite runAction:[CCTintTo actionWithDuration:1.5 red:156 green:0 blue:121]];
```